# How would I show liked/upvoted posts with the acts as votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Firstly, the gem I'm using is https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Hi there! I'm really new to rails and trying to build an application where a student can like an internship a company posts. So far I've got everything working but I want the student to be able to see the posts from companies they've upvoted.

So far this is my internship controller which was created just using scaffolding/haven't included all of it.

```html
class InternshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_internship, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  

  
  def upvote
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:id])
    @internship.liked_by current_student
    redirect_to internships_path
    #can change current_user to any other voter
  end

  def downvote
    @internship = Internship.find(params[:id])
    @internship.disliked_by current_student
    #can change current_user to any other voter
  end

  # GET /internships
  # GET /internships.json
  def index
    @internships = Internship.all
  end

  # GET /internships/1
  # GET /internships/1.json
  def show
  end
```

My Internship model

```html
class Internship < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :company
     acts_as_votable
end
```

My Student Model

```html
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_voter
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

My internships/index.html.erb where I want the student to be able to 'upvote' an internship.

```html
<% @internships.each do |internship| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= internship.title %></td>
        <td><%= internship.requirements %></td>
        <td><%= internship.location %></td>
        <td><%= internship.duraton %></td>
        <td><%= internship.deadline %></td>
        <td><%= internship.website %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', internship %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "upvote", like_internship_path(internship), method: :put %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "downvote", dislike_internship_path(internship), method: :put %></td>
```

My routes

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :students
  resources :internships do
     member do
     put "like",    to: "internships#upvote"
     put "dislike", to: "internships#downvote"
   end
 end
  devise_for :companies
```

So far this is working great! The last thing I want to do is make the student show the internships they've upvoted and I'm completely stuck. Do I have to put it in a new controller and views. I generated my student model with devise. Any help in the right direction would be great and thank you so much

Comment: Are you also sarahmarah? I put something like this in my other answer, I think.

Comment: Hi sorry no! But I am in a night class to learn programming where we are trying to solve the same issue and there's a girl with the same name. I'm using the votable gem if that makes it different and I can upvote fine. I just want to display what the user has upvoted if that makes sense Thanks for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your 'Show' link, I think you want to do something like:

```
<% @internships.each do |internship| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= internship.title %></td>
    <td><%= internship.requirements %></td>
    <td><%= internship.location %></td>
    <td><%= internship.duraton %></td>
    <td><%= internship.deadline %></td>
    <td><%= internship.website %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', internship_path(internship) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "upvote", like_internship_path(internship), method: :put %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "downvote", dislike_internship_path(internship), method: :put %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

It looks like you already have `before_action :set_internship, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` in your `InternshipsController`. So, I guess you just need to make a `show.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an instance method on Internship that can see if the Student voted for it and display that in your index table. `internship.voted_for_by?(current_student)` and then in the Internship model

```
def voted_for_by?(current_student)
  voting_student = votes_for.up.by_type(Student).voters.find_by(id: current_student.id)
  voting_student.blank?
end
```

The query might need work as I'm not too familiar with `acts_as_votable` but you may be able to work from this. And then based off of the boolean return, you can display a check or whatever you want to indicate the up vote